# Inner tag <anonymous/> inside of http tag from spring security

Tags: spring, security

Hy,

Having this very simple configuration in Spring security:

```
 <security:http use-expressions="true" >            

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USUARIO')"/>            

     <security:form-login/>         


  </security:http>
```

With this configuration, I thought I would enter in an infinite loop because when I fill in the login form and I send it, I thought this request would be intercepted by url pattern="/**" but it doesnt, it gives me ok access. Why?

I thought I had to code the next: "security:intercept-url pattern="/loginPage... access="permitAll" or use "anonymous" tag  but I dont.

Thanks